# How to force screen to stay awake for a certain time?

Tags: android, screen, flags

I'm building an Android application, and I need the screen of the mobile device to be awake for ten minutes. How can it be done?

I think it could be some timer, but there is another question then; how to set screen off programmatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10222999 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/21911153

Answer (score 2):

That is the old way how manage. Now, try to use this one:

```
     getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

and after 10 min. you should disable usin or :

```
     this.getWindow().setFlags(this.getWindow().getAttributes().flags & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
```

or :

```
      this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

You can calculate the timer using this peace of code:

```
   final Handler mTimerHandler = new Handler();
   final Handler threadHandler = new Handler();
   new Thread() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
                   threadHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                           public void run() {

                           // HERE THE CODE TO DISABLE THE FLAG

                           }
                   }, 10000);   //10 seconds
           }
   }.start();
```

if you want 10 min =  10 x 60 seconds x 1000 milisecods =  600 000    It is the value that you have to set up.

Edit: the solutions with WakeLock object are not recommended for Android anymore.

Comment: If it is working for you, could you chack as valid the answer! Thanks! p

Comment: Great Work Thanks Juan