# How do I turn off screen on Android?

Tags: android

When user press a button, I would like to set a timer and turn off the screen immediately.

Had searched but looks like it requires `DEVICE_POWER` permission, which only available for system app.

Is it possible for a normal app to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and

```
PowerManager.WakeLock acquire()
```

So something like

```
int field = PowerManager.class.getClass().getField("PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK").getInt(null);
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(field, getLocalClassName());

wakeLock.acquire();
```

Check out [acquire](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html#acquire()) and [Turn off screen programmatically when face is close the screen on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884181/turn-off-screen-programmatically-when-face-is-close-the-screen-on-android)