# Turn off the mobile screen in Android programming

Tags: android

How can I turn off the smartphone screen when my proximity sensor is 0.0, and when the screen is turned on more than 0.0? **Please answer quickly!** Thanks.

Comment: Begging for a quick answer is a good way to get downvoted. Furthermore, your question is way to broad, so I'm voting to close.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may find this useful https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html

In the link the related program code you may want to look into is

```
@Override 
protected void onResume() {
// Register a listener for the sensor.
super.onResume();
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

}

This might also be a repeated stackoverflow post to: [Turn off screen programmatically when face is close the screen on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884181/turn-off-screen-programmatically-when-face-is-close-the-screen-on-android)

Hope this helps!